# Como uma classe pode herdar de uma interface e de outra classe no Delphi

Tags: delphi, orientação-a-objetos, herança, interface, rtti

Estou criando uma pequena classe de persistência utilizando RTTI. Criei os atributos dos campos separados por tipo Ex: FieldString[], FieldInteger[] e etc..
Em um determinado momento eu preciso percorrer os atributos para encontrar um determinado campo, e eis questao. Atualmente da forma que esta, eu teria que primeiro verificar se o atributo é FieldString[], FieldInteger[], e depois comparar com a property 'Name' que cada classe possui. Então eu pensei em criar uma interface tipo IField com a property 'Name' e daí eu faria o cast. O problema é que as classes tem que implementar TCustomAttribute, 
Ex:

```
IField = interface
..
  property Name:string read GetName write SetName;
  property IsPk:string read GetIsPk write SetIsPk;
end;

TFieldString = class(TCustomAttribute, IField) 
...
  property Name:string read GetName write SetName;
  property IsPk:string read GetIsPk write SetIsPk;
end.

TFieldInteger = class(TCustomAttribute, IField) 
...
  property Name:string read GetName write SetName;
  property IsPk:string read GetIsPk write SetIsPk;
end.
```

e eu não sei como fazer isto.

Comment: Não entendi qual é sua dúvida, parece que você está no caminho certo. Que tal colocar na pergunta o código que fez até agora para entender melhor?

Comment: Ontem após pesquisar bastante, encontrei neste link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5353656/delphi-inherit-from-a-class-and-an-interface-adapter-pattern uma pergunta bem parecida, e a resposta foi que para conseguir fazer isto (herdar uma interface e uma classe), deve ser implementada na(s) classe(s) filha(s) os 3 métodos QueryInterface, _AddRef e _Release da TInterfacedObject. Mas não sei se isto é correto.

Comment: Sim, isso é correto. Toda classe que implementa uma interface precisa implementar esses três métodos, para poder ter suporte ao sistema de gerência de memória por contagem de referências e também para que a tipagem da interface possa ser testada em certos momentos. Em geral, quando se implementa uma Interface, se usa como ancestral a classe `TInterfacedObject`, que já tem esses métodos implementados, mas você também pode implementar se for necessário. Apenas cuidado, `TCustomAttribute` serve como ancestral para a criação de novos atributos de anotação, não para o uso que você quer dar.

Comment: Se a ideia é usar as classes descendentes de `TCustomAttribute` para anotar as propriedades da tua classe persistente, então recomendo que você siga a convenção do compilador e chame, por exemplo, de `TFieldStringAttribute`. Com relação ao teu problema em específico, não ficou claro para mim porque você precisa da interface. Poderia explicar melhor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Atributos no Delphi são apenas classes, quando se anota uma construção de linguagem com um atributo, o que se faz é instanciar uma classe e vinculá-la à construção para uso por RTTI. Assim, você pode evitar a interface (que de fato será para você apenas dor de cabeça) por meio de uma ancestral, como a seguir:

```
TFieldAttribute = class(TCustomAttribute)
private
  FName: string;
  FisPk: Boolean;
public
  constructor Create(const aName: string; aIsPk: Boolean=False);
  property Name:string read FName write FName;
  property IsPk: Boolean read FIsPk write FIsPk;
end;

TFieldStringAttribute = class(TFieldAttribute) 
end;

TFieldIntegerAttribute = class(TFieldAttribute) 
end;
```

E assim para todos os atributos, no entanto, eu não entendo porque você precisa de atributos específicos por tipo, visto que a Rtti já te dá a tipagem de cada property. No teu lugar eu teria apenas o atributo ancestral (`TFieldAttribute`) para identificar cada uma das propriedades mapeadas e usaria o tipo dessa própria propriedade para mapear para o teu meio de persistência.

Agora, se você tem casos onde tem tipos diferentes entre a propriedade Delphi e a coluna no banco de dados, então o que você pode fazer é criar mais um parâmetro no atributo para dizer isso. Por exemplo:

```
TFieldAttribute = class(TCustomAttribute)
private
  FName: string;
  FColumnType: string
  FIsPk: Boolean;
public
  constructor Create(const aName: string; aIsPk: Boolean=False); overload;
  constructor Create(const aName, aColumnType: string; aIsPk: Boolean=False); overload;
  property Name:string read FName write FName;
  property ColumnType: string read FColumnType write FColumnType;
  property IsPk: Boolean read FIsPk write FIsPk;
end;
```

Particularmente, eu teria um atributo próprio para PK. Aí ficaria:

```
TFieldAttribute = class(TCustomAttribute)
private
  FName: string;
  FColumnType: string
public
  constructor Create(const aName: string); overload;
  constructor Create(const aName, aColumnType: string); overload;
  property Name:string read FName write FName;
  property ColumnType: string read FColumnType write FColumnType;
end;

TPrimaryKeyAttribute = class(TFieldAttribute)
end;
```

Aí no teu código o que você precisa é testar o tipo do atributo usando o operador `is`. No caso de uma classe do tipo pessoa (exemplo típico) ficaria:

```
TPessoa = class
private
  [PrimaryKey('Id')]
  FId: Long;
  [Field('Nome')]
  FNome: string;
  [Field('Dt_Nasc', 'VARCHAR')]
  FNascimento: TDateTime;
public
  property Id: Long read FId;
  property Nome: string read FNome write FNome;
  property Nascimento: TDateTime read FNascimento write FNascimento;
end;
```

Imagino que isso vá te servir!

Comment: Na verdade eu resolvi separar exatamente por isso, eu estou tentando utilizar SQL Server e SQLITE. Mas vou tentar fazer o que você sugeriu  e criar a TFieldAttribute deixando a interface de lado.

Comment: Desta forma funcionou muito bem, obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Não tenho certeza se entendi sua pergunta (e não posso fazer comentários por conta da minha reputação), mas vou tentar responder pelo meu entendimento da pergunta inicial.

O Delphi não suporta herança múltipla, mas as classes podem implementar várias interfaces e você pode delegar a execução da interface para que possa simular meios de herança múltipla.

Suas interfaces precisam ser declaradas como `Interface(IInterface)` e suas classes concretas como `class(TInterfacedObject, IInterface)`. Seguindo o seu exemplo, ficaria da seguinte forma:

```
type

  IField = Interface(IInterface)
    // Declaração de métodos que deveram ser implementos pelas
    // classes que implementarem essa interface.
  end;

  TCustomAttribute = class(TInterfacedObject)
    // Declaração de métodos e atributos.
  end;

  TFieldString = class(TCustomAttribute, IField)
    // Declaração de métodos e atributos.
  end;

  TFieldInteger = class(TCustomAttribute, IField)
    // Declaração de métodos e atributos.
  end;

end.
```

**Fonte: http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/Article.asp?Name=Interface**

Espero ter ajudado!

Answer (score 0):

Acho que agora vai ficar claro. Por exemplo, na montagem do insert

```
  for RttiProperty in RttiType.GetProperties do
    for RttiAttribute in RttiProperty.GetAttributes do
      if RttiAttribute is TTypeInteger then
      begin
        if not TTypeInteger(RttiAttribute).IsIdentity then
        begin
          strFields := strFields + TTypeInteger(RttiAttribute).Name  + ',';
          strValues := strValues + QuotedStr( IntToStr( RttiProperty.GetValue(TObject(Obj)).AsInteger ) ) + ',';
        end;
      end
      else if RttiAttribute is TTypeString then
      begin
        if Trim( RttiProperty.GetValue(TObject(Obj)).AsString ) <> '' then
        begin
          strFields := strFields + TTypeString(RttiAttribute).Name  + ',';
          strValues := strValues + QuotedStr(RttiProperty.GetValue(TObject(Obj)).AsString) + ',';
        end;
      end;
    end;
```

eu percorro todos os atributos para pegar o nome e valor. Ok, mas seu eu quisesse pegar apenas os nomes dos campos, ainda assim eu teria que testar o tipo do atributo, um por um. O que eu queria é algo do tipo

```
if RttiAttribute is TField then
  strFields := strFields + TField (RttiAttribute).Name  + ',';
```

Mas para conseguir isto, a classe filha teria que implementar TField e TCustomAttribute, mas como não é possivel no DELPHI, eu criei a interface, mas mesmo assim não conseguia compilar, foi quando enviei a pergunta.